# Select / View Data From a TimeDate Column

Tags: php, mysql

i want to show or select from my table which 'log_timestamp' column date is (3/9/2016 or 3/20/2016 maybe) > format mm/dd/yyyy. can you give my some query of what i need?

```
UserID UserName Status  Absense_Time(sic)
     1 bray     Present  3/9/2016 13:46 (Format m/dd/yyyy) I
     1 bray     absense 3/14/2016 13:46
     1 bray     permit  3/20/2016 13:46
     2 john     permit   3/9/2016 13:46
     2 john     Present 3/14/2016 13:46
     2 john     absense 3/20/2016 13:46
     2 greg     absense  3/9/2016 13:46
     2 greg     permit  3/14/2016 13:46
     2 greg     present 3/20/2016 13:46
     4 dylan    present  3/9/2016 13:46
     4 dylan    present 3/14/2016 13:46
     4 dylan    permit  3/20/2016 13:46
     5 rick     present  3/9/2016 13:46
     5 rick     permit  3/14/2016 13:46
     5 rick     present 3/20/2016 13:46
```

thanks

Comment: start here http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Store dates as dates, not strings. Then get back to us.

Comment: What column type is Absense_Time in mysql ? If it's someting about date you can probably use some function from here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html . But it's odd that the seconds are missing.

Comment: hello.. the column is varchar data type. i cannt edit the data type because the database is given by project owner for me to continue. is that possible to get in string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but I think it's how to work with the `Absense_Time` column as dates.  Since it's `VARCHAR` you'll have to convert them to the `DATETIME` type with [STR_TO_DATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).  The formatting options are is documented as part of [DATE_FORMAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

```
STR_TO_DATE(Absense_Time, '%c/%e/%Y %T')
```

Now that it's converted to a [`DATETIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html) you can do date math on it and use all the [date functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date).  Note you'll need to supply dates you want to compare against in [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) which MySQL understands, else they'll also need to be converted with `STR_TO_DATE()`.

```
-- Find all users who were absent after March 1st, 2016.
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE DATE(STR_TO_DATE(Absense_Time, '%c/%e/%Y %T')) > '2016-03-01'
```

---

For the future you should look into getting `Absense_Time` converted to a proper `DATETIME` column.  This makes querying easier, it avoids formatting mistakes, and it can make it much *faster* by allowing the database to use indexes.

With an indexed `DATETIME` column, the database can use an index to quickly perform range searches such as `Absense_Time BETWEEN '2016-03-01' AND '2016-03-31'` or `Absense_Time > '2016-03-01'`.  It avoids having to look at and compare every row which will greatly improve query performance as the table size grows.  But if you must first convert a `VARCHAR` column to a `DATETIME` it cannot use that index.  It must do a conversion and comparison for every row in the table.